# Visualforce page on android

Tags: visualforce, pdf, android

i am facing a problem with a Salesforce Mobile application i have a custom button link: `apex/MyPage?Id=XXXX`
When i am clicking on it I have this error "page doesn't exist or invalid URL "
is there a way to open the visualforce page on salesforce 1  android ?or in the android native browser ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a forward slash in front of apex? `/apex/MyPage?Id=xxxx`

Comment: @MattLacey yes i did but still not working

Comment: @MattLacey it works on iOS

Answer (score 0):

1. Check “Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app” is checked for the vf page
2. Check the profile for the integration user has the vf page enabled (can skip this if the integration user for the iOS app is the same as for Android)
3. Turn on the debug logs for the integration user and see what you get when tapping on the link in the mobile app

Comment: the issue is that when i click on the button it redirect me on the browser and i have to log in my salseforce org in order to open the visualforce page !!?